# The parameter is incorrect error with InternetReadFileEx

Tags: c++, file

So im trying to read from a file in a website that I have using WinInet functions, and so I was able to do all the InternetConnect() functions and stuff successfully but when I try to do InternetReadFileExA() I keep getting error 87 which mean The parameter is incorrect and of course it doesnt tell me which one I have incorrect so I have no idea how to fix it, I think its probably the 4th parameter in the function which I have set to NULL because as usual Microsoft never tells you how to get specific values, all it says is "A caller supplied context value used for asynchronous operations." and it doesnt tell me what value I should use. Can anyone tell me what I have wrong and how to fix it? Here is my Code

```
HANDLE fileToSend;
HINTERNET iNetOpenHandle = InternetOpen(L"FileTransfer", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_FLAG_ASYNC);

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    HINTERNET connectHandle = InternetConnect(iNetOpenHandle, L"IMhidingTheIpHere", INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, INTERNET_NO_CALLBACK, NULL);

    PCWSTR acceptTypes[2] = {L"text/html", NULL};
    HINTERNET httpReq = HttpOpenRequest(connectHandle, NULL, L"Tutorials.html", NULL, L"http://www.dominihq.hoxty.com/Tutorials.html", acceptTypes, INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, NULL);



    if (httpReq != NULL) {
        cout << "Opened http request successfully" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Could not open http request" << endl;
        int errCode = GetLastError();
        cout << "Error Code: " << errCode << endl;
    }

    INTERNET_BUFFERSA iNetBuffer;
    bool readFileStatus = InternetReadFileExA(httpReq, &iNetBuffer, WININET_API_FLAG_ASYNC, NULL);

    if (readFileStatus == true) {
        cout << "ReadFile completed successfully!" << endl;
        cout << "Data: " << iNetBuffer.lpvBuffer << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Could not read file" << endl;
        int errCode = GetLastError();
        cout << "Error Code: " << errCode << endl;
    }

    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the part where the error is

```
bool readFileStatus = InternetReadFileExA(httpReq, &iNetBuffer, WININET_API_FLAG_ASYNC, NULL);
```

Comment: "A caller supplied context value used for asynchronous operations." means it's a value of your choosing to be passed to be passed to your own functions if you registered async callbacks.

Comment: You could actually have the wrong value. You should get the error code *first* before you do any other system calls (which will happen when you output using `cout`).

Comment: Why are you calling "InternetReadFileExA" instead of "InternetReadFileEx"?

Answer (score 0):

[`HttpOpenRequest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384233(v=vs.85).aspx) needs a handle created by `InternetConnect`. It creates another handle which is then used by `HttpSendRequest`.

You are just reading a webpage so you don't need any of that. Use [`InternetOpenUrl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385098(v=vs.85).aspx) instead of `HttpOpenRequest`. You can use `InternetReadFile` instead of `InternetReadFileEx`. Make sure the close the handles too.

```
#define UNICODE
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <WinInet.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "wininet.lib")//Visual Studio specific pragma for adding library

int main()
{
    std::string str;

    HINTERNET iNetOpenHandle = InternetOpen(L"FileTransfer", 
        INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
    if (iNetOpenHandle)
    {
        HINTERNET hurl = InternetOpenUrl(iNetOpenHandle, 
            L"http://www.dominihq.hoxty.com/Tutorials.html", NULL, 0,
            INTERNET_FLAG_DONT_CACHE, 0);
        if (hurl)
        {
            DWORD received;
            const int bufsize = 1024;
            char buf[bufsize];
            while (InternetReadFile(hurl, buf, bufsize, &received))
            {
                if (!received) break;

                //show progress...
                std::cout << ".";
                str.append(buf, received);
            }
            std::cout << "\n";
            InternetCloseHandle(hurl);
        }
        InternetCloseHandle(iNetOpenHandle);
    }

    std::ofstream f(L"filename.htm");
    f << str;

    return 0;
}
```

Note the result is probably in UTF-8, you may need to use `MultiByteToWideChar` to convert UTF-8 to UTF-16 if you want to display the result directly in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

If we take your code, fix the missing includes, and paste into an [online Visual Studio compiler](http://rextester.com/CIME10853)

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Wininet.h>
#include <WinSock.h>
#include <iostream>

HANDLE fileToSend;
HINTERNET iNetOpenHandle = InternetOpen(L"FileTransfer", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_FLAG_ASYNC);

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    HINTERNET connectHandle = InternetConnect(iNetOpenHandle, L"IMhidingTheIpHere", INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, INTERNET_NO_CALLBACK, NULL);

    PCWSTR acceptTypes[2] = {L"text/html", NULL};
    HINTERNET httpReq = HttpOpenRequest(connectHandle, NULL, L"Tutorials.html", NULL, L"http://www.dominihq.hoxty.com/Tutorials.html", acceptTypes, INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, NULL);



    if (httpReq != NULL) {
        cout << "Opened http request successfully" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Could not open http request" << endl;
        int errCode = GetLastError();
        cout << "Error Code: " << errCode << endl;
    }

    INTERNET_BUFFERSA iNetBuffer;
    bool readFileStatus = InternetReadFileExA(httpReq, &iNetBuffer, WININET_API_FLAG_ASYNC, NULL);

    if (readFileStatus == true) {
        cout << "ReadFile completed successfully!" << endl;
        cout << "Data: " << iNetBuffer.lpvBuffer << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Could not read file" << endl;
        int errCode = GetLastError();
        cout << "Error Code: " << errCode << endl;
    }

    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

We can see the default project settings give us a number of warnings relating to character-type conversions - you are specifying `L".."` instead of `_T("...")` which is only OK if we are using Unicode/MBCS.

```
source_file.cpp(7): error C2664: 'HINTERNET InternetOpenA(LPCSTR,DWORD,LPCSTR,LPCSTR,DWORD)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const wchar_t [13]' to 'LPCSTR'
source_file.cpp(7): note: Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
source_file.cpp(13): error C2664: 'HINTERNET InternetConnectA(HINTERNET,LPCSTR,INTERNET_PORT,LPCSTR,LPCSTR,DWORD,DWORD,DWORD_PTR)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'const wchar_t [18]' to 'LPCSTR'
source_file.cpp(13): note: Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
source_file.cpp(16): error C2664: 'HINTERNET HttpOpenRequestA(HINTERNET,LPCSTR,LPCSTR,LPCSTR,LPCSTR,LPCSTR *,DWORD,DWORD_PTR)': cannot convert argument 3 from 'const wchar_t [15]' to 'LPCSTR'
source_file.cpp(16): note: Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
```

What this tells us is that you're having a character-width issue, and sure enough

```
INTERNET_BUFFERSA iNetBuffer;
bool readFileStatus = InternetReadFileExA(httpReq, &iNetBuffer, WININET_API_FLAG_ASYNC, NULL);
```

there you are specifying a character type structure and function.

If we enable Unicode and [remove your 'A' specifiers](http://rextester.com/BJQ99440)

```
    INTERNET_BUFFERS iNetBuffer;
    bool readFileStatus = InternetReadFileEx(httpReq, &iNetBuffer, WININET_API_FLAG_ASYNC, NULL);
```

then the program compiles (it doesn't link on rextester because I didn't specify the libraries to include).

At no time was I able to reproduce the ambiguous error you reported, using VS2015, VS2013 or VS2010, but then I have the description box expanded so I can read all of it.

- Avoid using `L""` unless you are trying to write portable code, in which case you wouldn't be using Windows specific calls anyway. Use `_T("...")` instead

  InternetOpen(_T("FileTransfer"), INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_FLAG_ASYNC);
- Avoid using A/W suffixes unless you categorically have to (e.g. you can only write the function to take a 'char*' pointer)

  ```
  INTERNET_BUFFERS iNetBuffer;
  bool readFileStatus = InternetReadFileEx(httpReq, &iNetBuffer, WININET_API_FLAG_ASYNC, NULL);
  ```

Note that Microsoft's `BOOL` type is not the same as `bool`, so you may want to consider writing the last line as

```
    BOOL readFileStatus = InternetReadFileEx(httpReq, &iNetBuffer, WININET_API_FLAG_ASYNC, NULL);
```

or

```
    auto readFileStatus = InternetReadFileEx(httpReq, &iNetBuffer, WININET_API_FLAG_ASYNC, NULL);
```